# How do I run a bash script (that resides on a remote server) in windows task scheduler?

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

**SOLVED**

**Scenario**: I am a beginner in bash script, windows task scheduler and such. I am able to run a local bash script in my Windows Task Scheduler successfully.

**Problem:** I need to do this on many computers, thus I think storing just 1 copy of the bash script on a remote server may be of help. What my Task Scheduler needs to do is just to run the script and output a log. However, I can't get the correct syntax for the argument.
The below is what I have currently:

**Program/Script:** C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe

**Argument** (works successfully):

```
-l -c "ssh -p 222 ME@ME.com "httpdocs/bashscript.sh" >> /cygdrive/c/Users/ME/Desktop/`date +%Y%m%d`.log 2>&1"
```

**Start in:** C:\cygwin64\bin

Also had to make sure that the user account under Properties in Task Scheduler is correct, as mine was incorrect before. And need key authentication for ME@ME.com too.

Comment: The first issue I see is that `-c` is supposed to precede a *command*, but you have `--rsh-...`, which is a *parameter* to something. What *command* do you want to run?

Comment: @chrisaycock I want to run the bash script residing on ME.com and output a log to my computer. I was also wondering what to do with the password for ssh-ing to the server.

Comment: For the password issue, you really should use **ssh keys**. I think your command would simply be `ssh -p 222 ME@ME.com:...`. I.e., just get rid of the `--rsh` stuff.

Comment: @chrisaycock Will try that tmr morning. Midnight here. Thanks!

Comment: @chrisaycock Have tried it, seems to work! I should be getting somewhere as now I have an output log with an error message. Now I just need to resolve the error hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

For the password issue, you really should use **ssh keys**. I think your command would simply be `ssh -p 222 ME@ME.com:...`. I.e., just get rid of the `--rsh` stuff. – chrisaycock